# wxEffects is undefined

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have MSVC++ 15 and wxwidgets-3.1.0. I am following the book [Cross-Platform GUI Programming with wxWidgets (2005)](https://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/book/). I am stuck on this code from Chapter 5 "Drawing and Printing":

```
#include <wx/effects.h>

void MyWindow::OnErase(wxEraseEvent& event){

    wxClientDC* clientDC = NULL;

    if (!event.GetDC())
        clientDC = new wxClientDC(this);
    wxDC* dc = clientDC ? clientDC : event.GetDC() ;
    wxSize sz = GetClientSize();
    wxEffects effects;
    effects.TileBitmap(wxRect(0, 0, sz.x, sz.y), *dc, m_bitmap);

    if (clientDC)
        delete clientDC;
}
```

When I compile the code above I get the error: `Identifier "wxEffects" is undefined`.

Comment: I see that `wxEffects` is deprecated. https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/effects.h Not sure if you have to do something to enable deprecated classes in `wxWidgets`.

Comment: @drescherjm: would you suggest something as an alternative?. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @M.M: Yea the wxwidgets guide's chapter around "Drawing and Printing".

Comment: @drescherjm: How to do? and where to define?

Comment: @M.M: Normally yes. Could you suggest some other version?

Comment: @M.M: No. It is still the same.

Comment: @M.M: Yea I did. `wxGetApp().TileBitmap(wxRect(0,...` but the same.

Comment: @M.M: After I did what you suggest I got an error: `TileBitmap is not a member of MyApp`.

Comment: @drescherjm the implementation file also has the same macro check, so OP would need to entirely build wxwidgets with that define set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems `wxEffects` has been removed from a default build of wxWidgets, but without any replacement being added for the `TileBitmap` function.

If you build wxWidgets yourself then you could enable this by doing a 2.8 compatibility build (edit `include/wx/msw/setup.h` before building).

However if you are just using wxWidgets headers and precompiled libraries then an option could be to put in your own version of this function. The source code is [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/cc931612eec2e3ea49200ebff45042135f3c3f9c/src/common/effects.cpp) so you can just copy the entire `bool wxEffectsImpl::TileBitmap` out of that and into your program, remove the `wxEffectsImpl::` and make sure you've got the right headers included.

---

One of the [sample apps](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/f58ea625968953ca93585ea7f93dcc07ad032d8f/samples/dragimag/dragimag.cpp) has the following simplified version that might work for you:

```
bool TileBitmap(const wxRect& rect, wxDC& dc, wxBitmap& bitmap)
{
    int w = bitmap.GetWidth();
    int h = bitmap.GetHeight();

    int i, j;
    for (i = rect.x; i < rect.x + rect.width; i += w)
    {
        for (j = rect.y; j < rect.y + rect.height; j+= h)
            dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, i, j);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The sample actually made this a member of `MyApp` but you don't have to do that, you can just copy it into the `.cpp` file where you need it and call it directly.

Comment: Ohhh! Thanx! It really helps too much and saved the day. I do really appreciate you. I made your function above in my code and loaded an image then called your function. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

M.M's answer is already really good.  But here's a second way to do the TileBitmap function using a stipple brush instead of manually drawing the bitmap repeatedly.

```
bool TileBitmap(const wxRect& rect, wxDC& dc, wxBitmap& bitmap)
{
    wxBrush brush(bitmap);

    wxDCBrushChanger bc(dc, brush);
    wxDCPenChanger pc(dc, *wxTRANSPARENT_PEN);

    dc.DrawRectangle(rect);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time. I really appreciate you.